# how to expose current zend based web application actions using RESTFUL web services

Tags: php, web-services, rest, zend-framework

I want to expose my current zend based web application controller action and models by doing minimum modifications in existing code

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your existing code, you could try to write a proxy.

Without more information about your application controllers/models you will hardly get more precise answer.

In any case:

> No sweet without sweat.

Recommended reading (Zend Framework 1):

- [Zend_Rest_Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.rest.server.html)
- [Building RESTful Services with Zend Framework](https://mwop.net/blog/228-Building-RESTful-Services-with-Zend-Framework.html) - from Matthew Weier O'Phinney
- [RESTful services with Zend Framework 1.0](https://www.ahmadnassri.com/blog/restful-services-with-zend-framework/) - from Ahmad Nassri

There are some other articles for ZendFramework 2 and of course the [Apigility Project](https://apigility.org/) from Zend.

Comment: ok. i am ready to made some changes. now tell me what and how

Comment: You still provide no information about your application's architecture.